# Node-Traversal Style Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this kind of question but seeing as it was algorithm based, I felt it fit.

What I am trying to do is figure out or find out the name of an algorithm I can use to apply to the following...

Currently, this is what happens.

- I have a node tree that can have any number of starting nodes. (Not **exactly** a node tree, but the best analogy I could come up with).
- These nodes then branch off into any number of other nodes
- Resources are added to these nodes and associate themselves with all child nodes recursively.

Now the problem arises when I want to get all associated nodes for a particular resource. Getting all of them is fine, but not desirable. What I really want to do is only retrieve the **top-most** node for each association.

**Edit**

This is being done in JS using Sails as a framework with MySQL datasource.

```
{
    name: 'Some Node Name'
    children: [] // Array of child nodes
    parent: 1 // Id of the parent node or null if it is top-level
    resources: [] // Array of resources associated
}
```

If there is already an algorithm that tackles this already then I'd appreciate the direction.

Thanks.

Comment: This is more of a language specific problem, than a logarythmic one. In PHP you can use `array_filter`, `array_key`, and so on. In .NET, you can use LINQ and simply do a query for it.  It really depends on what language you are using as to how you can best approach the problem.

Comment: @KraangPrime I have updated my post slightly - Do you have a suggestion for JS?

Comment: sort of inheritance tree is what you are trying is it? when resource from root node is removed does it also get/should be removed from descendant nodes?

Comment: By "top most node" do you mean the node at the highest hierarchy level that contains a reference to the resource? Sounds like a pretty standard [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) problem.

Comment: Do you just want the node where `parent` is `null`? That should be easy, but the implementation will depend on how you are storing the nodes. Are they just in an array?

Comment: I do not have any specific suggestion, however you may be able to accomplish this using includes() and indexOf . Havn't worked with Sails, but the framework may have a wrapper for these methods ?!   (re-added this as I couldn't correct my typo due to time passed)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the nodes you term *top level resources* refers to theose nodes which are not referenced by any other node; in terms of graph theory, these are the ones with [indegree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) zero. From the description of the problem, these are the ones where `parent` is `null`.